# XmlNode.SelectNodes Returns 0 Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an xml like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <reflection-optimizer use="false"/>
    <session-factory>
           <property name="XX">XX</property>
           <property name="XX">XX</property>
    </session-factory>  
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm trying to select the property nodes using SelectNodes, and I've tried the following:

```
root.SelectNodes("property");
root.SelectNodes("//property");
root.SelectNodes("/session-factory/property");
root.SelectNodes("descendant::property");
root.LastChild.SelectNodes("child::property");
```

But all of them returns 0 nodes.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks.

Comment: It has to do with the namespace on the root node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this long answer:

[Why is XmlNamespaceManager necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178111/why-is-xmlnamespacemanager-necessary)

It has to do with the namespace on the root node.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(root.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2");

var nodes1 = root.SelectNodes("x:property", nsmgr);
var nodes2 = root.SelectNodes("/x:session-factory/x:property", nsmgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use LINQ to XML

```
    var xml = XDocument.Parse(
    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
    <hibernate-configuration xmlns=""urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2"">
    <reflection-optimizer use=""false""/>
    <session-factory>
    <property name=""XX"">XX</property>
    <property name=""XX"">XX</property>
    </session-factory>  
    </hibernate-configuration>");
    var properties = xml.Descendants().Where(p=>p.Name.LocalName.Equals("property")).ToList();
```

Check msdn for more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have it working using LINQ to XML, but I still want to figure out what I'm doing wrong with SelectNodes.