# create new node <xi:include>

Tags: xml, powershell

```bsh
$club = $xml.CreateElement('xi:include')
$club.SetAttribute('href','barracas')
$lookupNode.AppendChild($club) >$null
$xml.Save($config_filename)
```

In the above PowerShell fragment `$lookupNode` is the node where I am appending a newly created node `$club`.

What I expect is to add the line below.

```xml
<xi:include href="barracas" />
```

What actually I get is a line below.

```xml
<include href="barracas" xmlns="" />
```

The problems are:

1. I need `xi:include` but it starts with `include`.
2. I am getting `xmlns=""`, which I don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colon-separated prefix in XML elements indicates a [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx).

```
<foo:bar baz='something'>else</foo:bar>
  ^   ^   ^       ^       ^
  |   |   |       |       `- node value/text
  |   |   |       `- attribute value/text
  |   |   `- attribute name
  |   `- node name
  `- namespace name
```

You need a [namespace manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for handling these:

```bsh
[Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$nsm = $xml.NameTable
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
$nsm.AddNamespace('xi', 'http://...')

$club = $xml.CreateElement('xi:include', $ns.LookupNamespace('xi'))
$club.SetAttribute('href', 'barracas')
$xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($club) >$null
```

Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7178111/1630171).

Comment: I am getting like this :<xi:include href="barracas" xmlns:xi=" xmlns xml" />       How can I remove xmlns:xi=" xmlns xml"  and make a line like                         <xi:include href="barracas" />

Comment: @MuhammadVP To avoid that you need to explicitly add and look up the `xi` namespace. See updated answer.

Comment: @MuhammadVP What are you talking about? For an `<xi:something>` element to work there should already be a definition `xmlns:xi="http://..."` elsewhere in the XML. You can't use namespaced elements without the namespace being defined. `AddNamespace()` just informs the namespace manager about the namespace.

Comment: Is this a namespace/node with a `namespaced attr`? `<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/..'..` Node and attribute have similar namespace.