# Removing duplicate tags from XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

My problem is that I have a XML file that has the same value twice like:

```xml
<ns:html xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="2" release="1">
    <ns:Name>A
        <ns:ID>ANI-2016-05-02T21:01Z</ns:ID>
        <ns:CreationDate>2016-05-02T21:01:40</ns:CreationDate>
        <ns:Subname>A2
            <ns:Total>5000</ns:Total>
            <ns:type>ANI</ns:type>
        </ns:Subname>
    </ns:Name>

    <ns:Name>A
        <ns:ID>ANI-2016-05-02T21:01Z</ns:ID>
        <ns:CreationDate>2016-05-02T21:01:40</ns:CreationDate>
        <ns:Subname>A2
            <ns:Total>5000</ns:Total>
            <ns:type>ANI</ns:type>
        </ns:Subname>
    </ns:Name>

    <ns:Name>A
        <ns:ID>ANI-2016-08-04T21:01Z</ns:ID>
        <ns:CreationDate>2016-04-08T21:01:40</ns:CreationDate>
        <ns:Subname>A2
            <ns:Total>5000</ns:Total>
            <ns:type>ANI</ns:type>
        </ns:Subname>
    </ns:Name>
</ns:html>
```

My question is how can I use XML to remove the duplicate value from the XML file so that I get the following result in a new XML file. The check can be done on basis of ID.

```xml
<ns:html xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="2" release="1">
    <ns:Name>A
        <ns:ID>ANI-2016-05-02T21:01Z</ns:ID>
        <ns:CreationDate>2016-05-02T21:01:40</ns:CreationDate>
        <ns:Subname>A2
            <ns:Total>5000</ns:Total>
            <ns:type>ANI</ns:type>
        </ns:Subname>
    </ns:Name>

    <ns:Name>A
        <ns:ID>ANI-2016-05-02T21:01Z</ns:ID>
        <ns:CreationDate>2016-05-02T21:01:40</ns:CreationDate>
        <ns:Subname>A2
            <ns:Total>5000</ns:Total>
            <ns:type>ANI</ns:type>
        </ns:Subname>
    </ns:Name>
</ns:html>
```

I have tried the following things:

First I used the example as found [here](https://klemmestad.com/2014/08/08/removing-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-powershell/):

```bsh
## SETUP ENVIRONMENT
# Find "Advanced Monitoring Agent" service and use path to locate files
$gfimaxagent = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |
               Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Advanced Monitoring Agent' }
$gfimaxexe = $gfimaxagent.PathName
$gfimaxpath = Split-Path $gfimaxagent.PathName.Replace([char]34,"") -Parent #"Wordpress syntax highlighter bug
$XmlFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test.xml"
$Output = "C:\Users\Desktop\result.xml"

[xml]$XmlContent = Get-Content $XmlFile
$XmlPath = "checks"
$Property = "uid"
$XmlValues = @{}
foreach ($XmlElement in $XmlContent.$XmlPath.ChildNodes)
{
    $ElementValues = "" #"Wordpress syntax highlighter bug
    foreach($XmlValue in $XmlElement.ChildNodes | Sort-Object name)
    {
        $ElementValues = $ElementValues + $XmlValue.Name + $XmlValue.InnerText
    }
    $XmlValues[$XmlElement.$Property] = $ElementValues
}

$XmlDuplicates = @{}
foreach ($XmlValue in $XmlValues.Values)
{
    $Items = @($XmlValues.Keys | Where { $XmlValues[$_] -eq $XmlValue })
    if ($Items.Count -gt 1)
    {
        if (!($XmlDuplicates[$Items[0]])) { $XmlDuplicates[$Items[0]] = $Items }
    }

}

foreach ($XmlDuplicate in $XmlDuplicates.Keys)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $XmlDuplicates[$XmlDuplicate].Count; $i++)
    {
        $XPath = "//" + $XmlPath + "/*[@" + $Property +"=" + $XmlDuplicates[$XmlDuplicate][$i]+"]"
        $ChildToBeRemoved = $XmlContent.SelectSingleNode($XPath)
        $ChildToBeRemoved.ParentNode.RemoveChild($ChildToBeRemoved)
    }
}

$XmlContent.Save($Output)
```

The problem was even after I changed the source it still does not load my file but the original example file from the site.

As second I also tried it with the following code:

```bsh
[xml]$XmlDocument1 = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\EX27740\Desktop\testdubbel.xml

$softwareVersionsArray = $catalogXML.catalog.software |
    Group-Object name |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Group[0]}

$filename = ' C:\Users\EX27740\Desktop\Resultaat.xml'
$catalogXML.Save($filename)
```

But get an error:

> At line:8 Char:1 Cannot call a null-valued expression

Comment: can you provide an example with a root node?

Comment: SO is not a place where other people do your work for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: Hi sorry forgat to add thodse ti have added them now

Comment: You [still need a namespace manager](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39342742/1630171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to loop through the xml nodes and remove any duplicates

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<ns:html xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="2" release="1">
    <ns:Name>A
        <ns:ID>ANI-2016-05-02T21:01Z</ns:ID>
        <ns:CreationDate>2016-05-02T21:01:40</ns:CreationDate>
        <ns:Subname>A2
            <ns:Total>5000</ns:Total>
            <ns:type>ANI</ns:type>
        </ns:Subname>
    </ns:Name>

    <ns:Name>A
        <ns:ID>ANI-2016-05-02T21:01Z</ns:ID>
        <ns:CreationDate>2016-05-02T21:01:40</ns:CreationDate>
        <ns:Subname>A2
            <ns:Total>5000</ns:Total>
            <ns:type>ANI</ns:type>
        </ns:Subname>
    </ns:Name>

    <ns:Name>A
        <ns:ID>ANI-2016-08-04T21:01Z</ns:ID>
        <ns:CreationDate>2016-04-08T21:01:40</ns:CreationDate>
        <ns:Subname>A2
            <ns:Total>5000</ns:Total>
            <ns:type>ANI</ns:type>
        </ns:Subname>
    </ns:Name>
</ns:html>
"@

cls
$CreationDates=@()
$xml.html.Name | ForEach-Object {
  if($CreationDates -contains $_.CreationDate) {
    [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
  } else {
    $CreationDates += $_.CreationDate
  }
}
#$CreationDates
$xml.html.Name
```