# Inserting a PowerShell variable in XML

Tags: xml, powershell

Is it possible to insert a variable from PowerShell into an XML format? 
ex. I have declared 
$SIDadm = sidadm as a global variable and i want it to be inserted on xml code below

```xml
[xml]$REST2 = 
'<config xmlns="http://www.sap.com/lmsl/slp">
<Parameter>
<id>JeeAdminPassword</id>
<value>mkSVQW1zMi070N</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SidAdmUserPassword</id>
<value>cB8y@OSLHu@DcNPa</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>NoCredentialsMode</id>
<value>false</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SidAdmUserName</id>
<value>$SIDadm</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>EHPStackFile</id>
<value>F:/SAPSoftware/J3M_MII15.1_SP3_Patch_1/Stack_generic.xml</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[]</id>
<value>2</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[0].SidAdmUserPassword</id>
<value>cB8y@OSLHu@DcNPa</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[0].InstanceNumber</id>
<value>0</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[0].SidAdmUserName</id>
<value>GLOBEDDC\j3ladm</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[0].HostName</id>
<value>j3lsap</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[1].SidAdmUserPassword</id>
<value>cB8y@OSLHu@DcNPa</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[1].HostName</id>
<value>j3lsap</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[1].InstanceNumber</id>
<value>2</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[1].SidAdmUserName</id>
<value>GLOBEDDC\j3ladm</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>InstanceName</id>
<value>JC00</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SystemId</id>
<value>J3L</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>JeeAdminUser</id>
<value>Administrator</value>
</Parameter>
</config'

return $REST2
```

Basically I want to insert `$SIDadm`which has a value of sidadm into the XML. like this under the (id)SidAdmUserName(/id) its (value) would be 
(value)sidadm(/value)

```
[xml]$REST2 = 
'<config xmlns="http://www.sap.com/lmsl/slp">
<Parameter>
<id>JeeAdminPassword</id>
<value>mkSVQW1zMi070N</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SidAdmUserPassword</id>
<value>cB8y@OSLHu@DcNPa</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>NoCredentialsMode</id>
<value>false</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SidAdmUserName</id>
<value>sidadm</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>EHPStackFile</id>
<value>F:/SAPSoftware/J3M_MII15.1_SP3_Patch_1/Stack_generic.xml</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[]</id>
<value>2</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[0].SidAdmUserPassword</id>
<value>cB8y@OSLHu@DcNPa</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[0].InstanceNumber</id>
<value>0</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[0].SidAdmUserName</id>
<value>GLOBEDDC\j3ladm</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[0].HostName</id>
<value>j3lsap</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[1].SidAdmUserPassword</id>
<value>cB8y@OSLHu@DcNPa</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[1].HostName</id>
<value>j3lsap</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[1].InstanceNumber</id>
<value>2</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SapSystemInstance[1].SidAdmUserName</id>
<value>GLOBEDDC\j3ladm</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>InstanceName</id>
<value>JC00</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>SystemId</id>
<value>J3L</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<id>JeeAdminUser</id>
<value>Administrator</value>
</Parameter>
</config'

$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($REST2.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', $REST2.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

$xpath = '/ns:config/ns:parameter[ns:id/text()="SidAdmUserName"]/ns:value'

$REST2.SelectSingleNode($xpath, $nsm).'#text' = $SIDadm
$REST2.Save([Console]::Out)

return $REST2
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking here. Do you have XML with variables in it and want to expand the variables to their value? Insert the variables into the XML (template)? Insert their values into the XML (template)? Just a specific variable or all of them? Something else entirely?

Comment: i want to use the $SIDadm variable from powershell inside the xml format sorry for being unclear first time posting here @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand variables in an XML string you can use the [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) `$ExecutionContext`:

```bsh
$str = @'
<config xmlns="http://www.sap.com/lmsl/slp">
  <parameter>
    <id>SidAdmUserName</id>
    <value>$SIDadm</value>
  </parameter>
</config>
'@

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($str)
```

Beware that this will expand *all* expandable expressions in the string (e.g. something like `$(Get-ChildItem)` would be expanded as well).

If you want to expand just a variable in a single element you could try with a simple string replacement:

```bsh
$str = @'
<config xmlns="http://www.sap.com/lmsl/slp">
  <parameter>
    <id>SidAdmUserName</id>
    <value>$SIDadm</value>
  </parameter>
</config>
'@

$str.Replace('$SIDadm', $SIDadm)
```

However, that may also yield undesired results, e.g. if there are several variables starting with the same partial name. Something like

```xml
<config xmlns="http://www.sap.com/lmsl/slp">
  <parameter>
    <id>SidAdmUserName</id>
    <value>$SIDadm</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <id>SidAdmPassword</id>
    <value>$SIDadmPassword</value>
  </parameter>
</config>
```

would become

```xml
<config xmlns="http://www.sap.com/lmsl/slp">
  <parameter>
    <id>SidAdmUserName</id>
    <value>j3ladm</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <id>SidAdmPassword</id>
    <value>j3ladmPassword</value>
  </parameter>
</config>
```

In situations like that it's better to parse the XML, select the particular node, and replace the content of just that node:

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<config xmlns="http://www.sap.com/lmsl/slp">
  <parameter>
    <id>SidAdmUserName</id>
    <value>$SIDadm</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <id>SidAdmPassword</id>
    <value>$SIDadmPassword</value>
  </parameter>
</config>
'@

$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

$xpath = '/ns:config/ns:parameter[ns:id/text()="SidAdmUserName"]/ns:value'

$xml.SelectSingleNode($xpath, $nsm).'#text' = $SIDadm
$xml.Save([Console]::Out)
```

Note that you MUST use a [namespace manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653697/1630171) here, because your XML uses namespaces.

Comment: @Therealjubster Please do not accept an answer before you have verified that the proposed solution actually does what you expect it to do.

Comment: hello @AnsgarWiechers im getting an error it says  invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlDocument] doesn't contain a method named 'Replace'. when insert the .replace method

Comment: @Therealjubster That's because you mixed my examples. Don't do that. The first two examples use XML **strings**, whereas the last example uses an `XmlDocument` **object**. The latter does not have a `Replace()` method.

Comment: hmm so is there anyway for my variable $SIDadm to be inserted into a XML template?

Comment: @Therealjubster I showed you 3 different ways in my answer, didn't I? Why don't you update your question with a sample of what your XML template looks like now, and what you want it to look like after the intended modification?

Comment: @Therealjubster Before ***and*** after. Show how the *result* is supposed to look like as well.

Comment: ok here its updated and thank you again for helping me with my problem of mine really appreciate it

Comment: @Therealjubster See updated answer. Also, note that there's a closing angular bracket missing at the end of the XML strings in your question.

Comment: Umm question sorry if this would sound stupid haha but under the line code
$xml.SelectNodes($xpath, $nsm).'#text' = $SIDadm. Is '#Text' where i am suppose to put the word to be replaced?

Comment: @Therealjubster How about you actually ***try*** it and see what it does, instead of waiting for me to spoon-feed you a solution?

Comment: Sorry to bother but when i ran it i get the error Property '$SIDadm' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable. i inserted $SIDadm onto #Text since from my understanding thats the value i want to change. Its my first time in powershell using xml im really sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Well, yes, you need to actually define `$SIDadm = 'j3ladm'` before you can use the variable. Did you expect it to suddenly appear out of thin air?

Comment: i decalred my $SIDadm as a global variable and is also declared before running this code, from my understanding the line ( correct me if wrong but ) $xml.SelectNodes($xpath, $nsm).'#text' im am selecting the node <id>SidAdmUserName</id <value>$SIDadm</value> and im replacing the value to the value i want right?

Comment: Ah, I see. I had 2 mistakes in the code handling the XML. The XPath expression needed to use the namespace identifier, and `SelectNodes()` returns a collection, which doesn't have a property `#text`. See updated answer.

Comment: $REST2.SelectSingleNode($xpath, $nsm).'$SIDadm' = $SIDadm. I am now using this and it still giving me the same error

Comment: The property name is still `.'#text'`, not `.'$SIDadm'`.

Comment: hello again after much researching im still getting the same error Property '#text' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable. I set the '$SIDadm' to '#text' and im still getting the same error

Comment: i have updated the code from above that is my current code right now

Comment: XPath is case sensitive. The `<Parameter>` tags in your XML are written with a capital `P`.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU @AnsgarWiechers ITS WORKING sorry for the questions but i really learned alot THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!