# Replace text between two string powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, file-get-contents

I have a question which im pretty much stuck on..

I have a file called xml_data.txt and another file called entry.txt

I want to replace everything between `<core:topics> and </core:topics>`

I have written the below script

```
$test = Get-Content -Path ./xml_data.txt
$newtest = Get-Content -Path ./entry.txt
$pattern = "<core:topics>(.*?)</core:topics>"
$result0 = [regex]::match($test, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
$result1 = [regex]::match($newtest, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
$test -replace $result0, $result1
```

When I run the script it outputs onto the console it doesnt look like it made any change.

Can someone please help me out

Note: Typo error fixed

Comment: Use `$test = Get-Content -Path ./xml_data.txt -Raw`, and `$pattern = "(?s)<core:topics>(.*?)</core:topics>"`

Comment: [DO NOT parse XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171). For manipulating XML data use PowerShell's builtin XML parser. Beware that your data apparently is using [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653697/1630171), so you need to take care of that.

Comment: `$test -replace [regex]::Escape($result0), $result1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What if I have mutiple entry how will i loop that

Comment: Sorry,  I think your question is rather unclea and a bit too broad.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Dont Worry, i got it working! your first solution did the trick thank you :)

Comment: I added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three main issues here:

- You read the file line by line, but the blocks of texts are multiline strings
- Your regex does not match newlines as `.` does not match a newline by default
- Also, the literal regex pattern must  when replacing with a dynamic replacement pattern, you must always dollar-escape the `$` symbol. Or use simple string `.Replace`.

So, you need to

- Read the whole file in to a single variable, `$test = Get-Content -Path ./xml_data.txt -Raw`
- Use the `$pattern = "(?s)<core:topics>(.*?)</core:topics>"` regex (it can be enhanced in case it works too slow by unrolling it to `<core:topics>([^<]*(?:<(?!</?core:topics>).*)*)</core:topics>`)
- Use `$test -replace [regex]::Escape($result0), $result1.Replace('$', '$$')` to "protect" `$` chars in the replacement, or `$test.Replace($result0, $result1)`.